# Hibernate Reserved keyword escaping not working

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am getting below error due to the use of `MYSQL` reserved keywords in hibernate models.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'when, who, why) values ('ICL670A - Project Deliverable - HAQ 1 - FDA-IR', null, ' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:970) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1109) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at
```

I have below property set in my `application.properties` file, it used to work before, but now it's not working and I am unable to figure out why.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

Now I have to escape the columns manually in my model definition for it to work.

```
@Column(name = "`who`")
private String who;

@Column(name = "`when`")
private Date when;

@Column(name = "`why`")
private String why;
```

How can I further debug for the same? How can I ensure that this property is being picked up?

Answer (score -1):

We are using multiple DB connections in our spring boot project. So all the hibernate properties need to be configured in the `DataSourceConfigurationFile`

```
@Primary
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean idotdbEntityManager() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(idotdbDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.novartis.idot.model");

    final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    final HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("spring.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers"));
    properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings",  env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings"));
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return em;
}


@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSourceProperties idotdbDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource idotdbDataSource() {
    return idotdbDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}

@Primary
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager idotdbTransactionManager() {
    final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(idotdbEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```